# Contructing basis vectors using the metric tensor

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I have 2 sets of basis vectors,

$e = (e_1,e_2)$ and $\tilde{e} = (\tilde{e_1},\tilde{e_2})$

$e$ is orthonormal.
I also have the metric tensor $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}$ in terms of the $\tilde{e}$ basis.

I want to construct the $\tilde{e}$ basis in terms of the $e$ basis.
Or in other words, I want to find the transform $F_{ij}$ using the metric $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}$ such that,

$\tilde{e_1} = F_{11}e_1 + F_{12}e_2$
$\tilde{e_2} = F_{21}e_1 + F_{22}e_2$

Is this possible? Or am i missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have two different orthonormal bases, then the metric components are the same. So you can’t use that to determine one basis in terms of the other. (Said another way, the mapping from bases to metric components is not one-to-one so you can’t go back).

Comment: @peek-a-boo not really. Only one basis is orthonormal. Other one is not even orthogonal.

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. Im saying that if even in the simple case of two orthonormal bases you can’t determine one from the other using only the metric components, then what hope do you have of doing it in a more general case? The answer is you can’t… unless you actually wanted to ask a different question. Anyway, the metric does NOT tell you how to go from one basis to another

Comment: @peek-a-boo my apologies. so if I understand correctly, in the case of 2D orthonormal bases there could be a rotation that the metric couldn't account for, so we cant determine the basis vectors uniquely. But if we specify one of the basis vectors, we should be able to determine the other using the metric right? So can we construct a linear map from $e \to \tilde{e}$ using that method?

Comment: No, there are still two choices for the other one. Bottom line is it is not the job of the metric tensor to modify bases. The way you change bases is by fixing an invertible linear map on the given vector space (i.e isomorphisms map bases to bases).